# How to augment structures with tag types in a way that doesn't prevent implementing Clone/Send/Sync in Rust?

Tags: rust

In C++ I can use a template parameter as a tag, to make identical yet unrelated datatypes:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct UniqueId 
{
    int Value;
};

struct CustomerTag{};
struct BookTag{};

using BookId = UniqueId<BookTag>;
using CustomerId = UniqueId<CustomerTag>;
```

I can do the same thing in Rust, but run into problems because my type starts acting like it *owns* a T, which it does not. So now, in order to make my type `Clone`, `Send`, etc. *my tags must also be* `Clone`, `Send`, etc.. This is a little odd since my type doesn't really own the `T`, just uses it as a parameter. Is there any way around this? The documentation seems to suggest `PhantomData<*const T>` will fix this problem:

```
struct UniqueId<T> {
    value: i32,
    phantom: PhantomData<*const T>
}
```

but it doesn't seem to because then I just get `*const BookTag cannot be sent between threads safely` errors instead of `BookTag cannot be sent between threads safely` errors.

Comment: As long as your tags are empty structs, they should implement `Send` and `Sync` (although you would indeed need to impl `Copy` and `Clone` for all tags).

Comment: You might be able to do `PhantomData<Rc<RefCell<T>>>` . The type inside `PhantomData` doesn't actually matter and `Rc` can implement `Clone` regardless of the inner type

Comment: NIT: in Rust its more commonplace to call these *"marker"* types instead of *"tags"*.

Comment: @kmdreko I'm not convinced they're the same. By `tag` I'm referring to *tag-dispatching*, from the docs it looks like Rust's markers are a much broader concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PhantomData<fn(T) -> T>`, which is invariant over T and always `Copy`, `Clone`, `Send`, and `Sync`. The only downside is that you will have to write manual `Copy` and `Clone` implementations for your `UniqueId<T>` struct, because the derive macros currently always generate a `T: Copy`/`T: Clone` bound, even when it is unnecessary (see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925)).

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d294511484808b321a146f87a7923aa8)

Comment: Almost. Better to use `fn() -> T` which is covariant over `T`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Any particular reason covariance would be preferable in this scenario?

Comment: Nope. Just less restrictive.

Comment: There's also just `fn(T)` to make it *contravariant* over T. :) Though when used as a marker, it should probably be invariant. Otherwise its possible to get into awkward places where a `UniqueId<X>` should always be different from a `UniqueId<Y>`, but the compiler could coerce them.